# Scikit-learn grid search with SVM regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am learning cross validation-grid search  and came across this [youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5-da3qGB5ICeMbQuqbbCOQWcS6OYBr5A) and the tutorial also has been uploaded to the [github](https://github.com/justmarkham/scikit-learn-videos/blob/master/08_grid_search.ipynb) as an ipython notebook. I am trying to recreate the codes in the **Searching multiple parameters simultaneously** section but instead of using knn i am using SVM Regression. This is my code

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

k=['rbf', 'linear','poly','sigmoid','precomputed']
c= range(1,100)
g=np.arange(1e-4,1e-2,0.0001)
g=g.tolist()
param_grid=dict(kernel=k, C=c, gamma=g)
print param_grid
svr=svm.SVC()
grid = GridSearchCV(svr, param_grid, cv=5,scoring='accuracy')
grid.fit(X, y)  
print()
print("Grid scores on development set:")
print()  
print grid.grid_scores_  
print("Best parameters set found on development set:")
print()
print(grid.best_params_)
print("Grid best score:")
print()
print (grid.best_score_)
# create a list of the mean scores only
grid_mean_scores = [result.mean_validation_score for result in grid.grid_scores_]
print grid_mean_scores
```

But its giving this error

> raise ValueError("X should be a square kernel matrix") ValueError: X
>   should be a square kernel matrix

Comment: When reporting a Python error you should always quote the full Python traceback at it gives information on where the exception was raised.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Remove `'precomputed'` from your parameter space.

`kernel='precomputed'`can only be used when passing a `(n_samples, n_samples)` data matrix that represents pairwise similarities for the samples instead of the traditional `(n_samples, n_features)` rectangular data matrix.

See the documentation for more details on the meaning of the kernel parameter:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-kernels

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply but can you tell me how we can export this model is this the correct way `>>> from sklearn.externals import joblib
>>> joblib.dump(grid, 'my_model.pkl', compress=9)`